# Javascript: Private Members (using closure), why can't functions added after initialization access private members?

Tags: javascript, closures, private

```
 test = (function(){var key = 200; 
  return {getKey : function(){return key} };          
 })();

test.getKey() //returns 200, so far so good

test.setKey() = function(arg){key = arg};

test.setKey(400);

test.getKey() //still returns 200, setKey cannot access the private member "key"
```

Now, this behavior is probably a good thing.  But it break my intuition for how closure works.  Isn't the link between the anonymous "*private* function and the return object?  When I add setKey isn't it then part of the returned object (test)?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Variables belong to an execution context that is created when entering that context, they can't be added later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it this way: A closure is a reference to the current scope chain. Only something which references the same scope will be modifying the same variable. This section is the scope in which the `key` variable exists:

```
{var key = 200; 
  return {getKey : function(){return key} };          
 }
```

Your set function is defined outside this scope and thus modifies a different variable named `key`. Closures and scopes are not connected to objects. If you wanted to be able to add the set function later, you would need to make the variable an actual member of the object:

```
test = (function(){
  return {key: 200, getKey : function(){return this.key} };          
 })();

test.getKey() //returns 200, so far so good

test.setKey = function(arg){this.key = arg};

test.setKey(400);

test.getKey() //returns 400
```